# Concurrent array access by executor service

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, happens-before

Are array elements correctly published between workers?

Suppose I have a big array (of any atomic data type, so not `long` or `double`),

- I create a worker that fills the array that I pass to it's contructor,
- I submit the worker to an executor, and wait until it's complete (*e.g.* with `future.get()`). The worker doesn't return anything. It just fills my array.
- Then, I immediately create and submit another worker with the same array in it's contructor. Does it see the latest values?

In other words, it it guaranteed that the last write of the previous worker happens-before the first read of the next worker?

Should I instead (or for best practice or something) let the first worker return the array, even though the reference is the same as the one I have already have?

[Edit] Some background: I use either `byte` arrays or `short` arrays, which represent images and use up to 500,000,000 elements each. I perform simple arithmetic on each element.

Comment: This sounds like you might be doing something that would work better with a Queue structure like ConcurrentLinkedQueue.

Comment: It's not a fifo. The second worker needs random access into the array.

Comment: I found something like this in some tutorial: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp03304/jsr133.gif but I'm not sure how to interpret this in the case of global variables. Is *everything* synced to internal RAM when a thread is unlocked and another locks? Does the executor do locking like this internally nor not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [package java.util.concurrent JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html):

> The methods of all classes in java.util.concurrent and its subpackages extend these guarantees to higher-level synchronization. In particular:
>
> Actions taken by the asynchronous computation represented by a Future happen-before actions subsequent to the retrieval of the result via Future.get() in another thread.
>
> Actions in a thread prior to the submission of a Runnable to an Executor happen-before its execution begins. Similarly for Callables submitted to an ExecutorService.

According to that it seems pretty safe to access an array from the second worker in your scenario.

Comment: I just read the passage `Actions taken by the task represented by a Future happens-before another thread returns from Future.get;` in Java Concurrency in Practice p344 (Goetz et al 2006) and thought I'd answer my own question, but I must have missed yours somehow.

Answer (score 2):

The elements of the array aren't [volatile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html), so they might be cached per-thread by the CPU. It's therefore possible for the first worker to initialize some array element, but for the second worker to not see it due to caching.

To make sure that the array elements are themselves atomic, you can use an [AtomicReferenceArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReferenceArray.html)

Comment: What about performance? When I changed the first workers to allocate and return a new array, and copy the arrays over the original one in the main thread, it became 3 times slower with 8 workers in parallel.

Comment: One of the problems is memory. With a `short` array, my program uses two 1GiB arrays. With `int` arrays, I get `OutOfMemoryError` (even with `-Xmx8G`). I just profiled an `AtomicReferenceArray`, and it uses ~4.7 bytes per element. Next, performance. Processing `byte` arrays takes me ~640ms. Processing `short` arrays takes me ~1100ms. I'm not even going to test it with an `AtomicReferenceArray` that constantly boxes/unboxes.

Comment: volatile is not relevant in this situation as per the answer provided by Denis Iskhakov, which points to the documentation of java.util.concurrent.